# Is there a such thing as a gas that stay a gas?

Tags: gas-laws

We know if you heat a liquid up it becomes a gas. But I need to know if there is a such thing as a element that is already a gas And will stay that way. If there is a such thing how could one keep it that way? Is there a certain temperature it must stay at what?

If there is no such gas, is there something that comes close to it?

Comment: Look around you. Oxygen and nitrogen are such elements: they are already gases and will stay that way, unless you cool them down to extremely low temperatures.

Comment: The closest you can get to is probably [helium, which does not have a solid phase at ambient pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium#Liquid_helium)

Answer (score 4):

A gas cannot be condensed to liquid no matter how high a pressure is applied if the temperature of the gas is higher than the critical temperature of the gas.